# MySQL Query - Select all posts and count comments for each one

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-select

It's 3:30 AM in my country so I need to sleep but I can't without this:

I'm trying to get all posts (using `Zend_Db`) and count comments for each one.

**Schema**

`blog_posts`:

```
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title         | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| content       | text             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| alias         | varchar(100)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id       | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_date  | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| modified_date | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| thumbnail     | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And here's `blog_comments`:

```
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id       | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| post_id       | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| comment       | text             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_date  | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| modified_date | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

*Note: the `blog_comments.post_id` is linked with `blog_posts.id`.*

---

**I would like a resulting table like that:**

```
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title         | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| content       | text             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| alias         | varchar(100)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id       | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_date  | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| modified_date | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| thumbnail     | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| TEMPOROARY COLUMN IN OBJECT ($post->comment)                             |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| comments      |                  |      |     |         |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

---

Now, here's the query I have for now:

```sql
SELECT `p`.*, `c`.*
FROM `blog_posts` `p`
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM `blog_comments` `c`
    WHERE c.post_id = p.id
) ON `p`.`comments`;
```

But it give me an error:

```
Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias
```

So if someone can help me, it would be very appreciated!

---

***IMPORTANT NOTE***
I'm using `Zend_Db` and `Zend_Db_Select` so I must be able to use the functions like `joinLeft()` or anything I need.

This is in my model for the `select()`:

```php
$select = $this->table->select();

if ($alias) {
    $select->where('alias = ?', $alias);
    return $this->table->fetchRow($select);
}
if ($withComments) {
    // I WILL PLACE THE CODE HERE, EXEMPLE:
    $select->joinLeft(...);
}
```

Comment: To get rid of the error message, you will have to write JOIN (SELECT ...) _AS counts_ ON ...  However, there seems to be other problems with your query as well (you should e.g return a key together with the count from the subselect, and the on clause is missing a condition.

Comment: @TerjeD. Can you explain a little please? I know MySQL for the base query but when I need to do something harder, I refer to SO 'cause the `JOIN` and etc. aren't my force!

Comment: Show an example of what the resulting table should look like.

Comment: @TerjeD. I added a section with the resulting table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT p.*, x.*
FROM blog_posts p
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) as cc
    FROM blog_comments
    GROUP BY post_id
) x 
ON x.post_id = p.id;
```

Comment: `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'p.id' in 'where clause'`

Comment: @Frederick: I've edited it to remove the WHERE in the inline select

Comment: Now, I need to convert it to a `Zend_Db_Select` -_-